# Why do I get Fortran 'End of record' error on PC with Fedora, but not on Macbook?

Tags: fedora, macos, fortran

I have a program which works well when using Macbook, but as soon as I try it on PC with Fedora 28, I get this error:

```
At line 107 of file transport.f08
Fortran runtime error: End of record
Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f2e56fe039a
#1  0x7f2e56fe0f09
#2  0x7f2e56fe1711
#3  0x7f2e571e6818
#4  0x7f2e571f2022
#5  0x7f2e571e97fa
#6  0x7f2e571e9c14
#7  0x403e5a
#8  0x405d0c
#9  0x405e65
#10  0x7f2e5643b1ba
#11  0x400bc9
#12  0xffffffffffffffff
```

Here is the block of code with problematic line 107:

```
subroutine outputs(i_out)
    integer, intent(in) :: i_out
    integer :: iunit, ierr
    integer :: i

     character(len=8) :: chout
     write(chout,fmt='(I0.4)') i_out    ! LINE 107

     open(newunit=iunit,file="./outputs/Houtput"//trim(chout)//".dat",&
     action="write", iostat=ierr)

    if( ierr /= 0) then
            print *, " > There was an error while opening output file ", i_out
            print *, " > Exiting..."
            stop
    endif

    do i=1,Nr
            write(iunit,fmt='(20E14.6)') r_cell(i), velocity(i), pressure(i), density(i)
    enddo

    close(iunit)

end subroutine outputs
```

Comment: I believe the input file is the same. What do you mean by line ending? Suffix is always .f08 if that's what you mean.

Comment: Which line is line 107? Why "fmt='(20E14.6)'" and not "fmt='(4E14.6)'". Try to compile with an option line '-g' to get more debug output.

Comment: @francescalus line endings (of the ".dat" file I assume you mean) shouldn't be a problem as it looks to me that we are here in a write routine.

Comment: @albert, true.  No idea how I misread that...

Comment: What is a typical value of `i_out`?  If more than eight digits (or seven if negative) you can expect to see that error.

Comment: Make the variable chout len=11 to make sure all possible 32-bit integers fit.

Comment: @francescalus and I misread where line 107 is ( :-( ).

Comment: Thanks, making sure i_out is short solves the error. I still don't know why Mac was ok with this, but it's not that important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As francescalus pointed out in the comments, I had to drop i_out length to 8 or less digits. It solved the error.

I still don't know why it worked on Mac before, but having the error solved is enough for me :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Does the Mac give the same number as the PC version? If not you should check why the difference occurs (but that is a completely different problem from this question), when the same the problem might be due to the different memory layout / how the variables lie in the memory  / on the stack (but in that case you were "lucky" at the moment on the Mac, solving the underlying issue i.e. length issue is the better solution).